# Design and Output are totally diiferent in Android Studio

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

When I run the demo project it just shows name TextView.
What should I do? Any solution?
Expectation:
[image: Expectation]

Reality:

[image: Reality]

Comment: Please explain in detail and post your code.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your (layout from android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout)

to (RelativeLayout)

and change the EditText
and Button
and TextView
depend on RelativeLayout

try this code i make it if that work fine change the attrib for your case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/"
android:padding="80dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.Just getting started in android development.

Comment: anytime don't forget to replace your background image here it will show error android:background="@drawable/"